# obtain grails url mappings from memory

Tags: url, grails, mappings

hi i want to obtain the grails url mappings from memory and change them dynamically.
My doubt is where to get the url mappings from memory programatically ? is it available in the grailsapplication?

Answer (score 11):

There's a `UrlMappingsHolder` Spring bean under the `grailsUrlMappingsHolder` name, so you can access the array of `UrlMapping` with:

```
def grailsUrlMappingsHolder
...
UrlMapping[] urlMappings = grailsUrlMappingsHolder.urlMappings
```

Comment: For groovy files that do not have automated dependency injection, like security providers using the Spring security plugin, there also needs to be a couple lines in the `resources.groovy` file to inject this dependency. For instance, a rough example: `myAuthenticationProvider("MyAuthenticationProvider") { grailsUrlMappingsHolder=ref("grailsUrlMappingsHolder") }`